# Simplify if conditions when .get return None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is it possible to simplify this:

```
def method(self, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('profile_id') is None:
        kwargs['profile_id'] = 'something1'
    if kwargs.get('status') is None:
        kwargs['status'] = 'something2'
    if kwargs.get('account_type') is None:
        kwargs['account_type'] = 'something3'
    if kwargs.get('external_account_id') is None:
        kwargs['external_account_id'] = 'something4'
    if kwargs.get('vendor') is None:
        kwargs['vendor'] = 'something5'
    if kwargs.get('created_timestamp') is None:
        kwargs['created_timestamp'] = 'something6'

    return ClassOne.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

This works, but I'm just curious if there is something more elegant. I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
kwargs['profile_id'] = kwargs.get('profile_id') or 'something1'
```

Comment: Try defining a default dictionary, with the keys and their default values.  Then do `adict.update(kwargs)`.  The `kwargs` values will overwrite the defaults where given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.get()` has an optional second argument, which is the default value.

```
kwargs['profile_id'] = kwargs.get('profile_id', 'something1')
```

Also, instead of calling `get()` in your `if` statements, you can use

```
if 'profile_id' not in kwargs:
```

Note that these solutions won't replace explicit `None` values in the dictionary.

You could use a dictionary of defaults for all the fields, and merge them.

```
defaults = {"profile_id": "something1", "status": "something2", ...}
kwargs = {**defaults, **kwargs}
```

See [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: Yes, but what if the value for the key is None as well? In your code it stays as `None`, but in the original code it gets replaced as well

Comment: @Ralf I've updated the answer to mention this caveat.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to use a loop to write the `if` only once:

```
for k, new_val in [
    ('profile_id', 'something1'),
    ('status', 'something2'),
    ...
]:
    if kwargs.get(key) is None:
        kwargs[key] = new_val
```

Note: this will also replace the value for `key` with `new_val` in cases where `key` is present with value `None` in `kwargs`.